# AS3 FacebookMobile graph api - user piture is_silhouette

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, air

im currently working on facebook integration into my mobile AS3 game. I'am downloading friends pictures, which works just fine:

```
    public function updateView(id:String, data:Object):void {
        FacebookMobile.api("/me/friends/",getfellaz);
        startLoading();

    }

    private function getfellaz(response:Object, fail:Object):void {     
        var a:int = response.length;
        arr = new Array();
        arr2 = new Array();
        var tempArrIDs:Array = new Array
        var k:int = 0
        for (var i:int = 0; i< a; i++ ) {
            arr.push(FacebookMobile.getImageUrl(response[i].id, 'large'));
            tempArrIDs.push(response[i].id);
        }
        arrLength = arr.length-1;
        for(var x:int = 0; x<12; x++) {
            var r:int = dejMiTyRandomy();
            randomUserPicArray.push(arr[r]);
            randomUserPicArray.push(arr[r]);
            uids.push(tempArrIDs[r]);
        }
        loadThatShit(0);
    }
```

then i draw pictures to bitmaps and work with them further... which is unrelated to my problem, i just can't figure out how to get " is_silhouette " property from user (in this case response object) object.

i tried to access this property

```
     response[i].picture.is_silhouette
```

but that is appearently undefined, but when i try to acces users name,id...etc. this way, it works, like this:

```
     response[i].id
```

and so on...

my question is, how do i access picture.is_silhouette property within this construction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `getImageUrl` method to be the `api` method, with a call to "friend_id/picture" where "friend_id" is the id of the friend. **Make sure that you append "?redirect=false" to get the json response.**

Here's a method call with mine:

`https://graph.facebook.com/20001655/picture?redirect=false`

Here's the logic (completely written / untested):

```
public var hasSilhouette:Boolean = false;

...

hasSilhouette = false;
checkHasImage(response[i].id)

if(hasSilhouette){
...
} else {
...
}

public function checkHasImage(user_id:int):void
{
  FacebookMobile.api(user_id+"/picture", checkHasImageResponse);
}

public function checkhasImageResponse(result:Object, fail:Object):void
{
  hasSilhouette = result.is_silhouette;
}
```

This returns a JSON response like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-frc1/somenumbers.jpg", 
    "is_silhouette": false
  }
}
```

is_silhouette is not part of the response from the "FacebookMobile.getImageUrl(response[i].id,...) method.

I believe you will have better luck using this Facebook documented method: (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#pictures)

In the future, I would handle testing by outputting the "response" object. That will show you everything you're getting. In this case, the "response" comes from */me/friends/* and doesn't have a reference to the "pictures" object.

Last, it's helpful to test Graph API calls in their Graph API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: seems reasonable enough to try that, thanks, i'll definately look into it. I'll let you now about results :)

Comment: Ok, then add a check first to see if the user has a silhouette / if they have an image set, if they do, then use the method you have defined, if not, use whatever placeholder photo you have.

Comment: sorry, about the edit... my previous comment just didnt make any sense after your edited your answer

Comment: Sure. By the way, I hate the callback structure / reference to a global variable in this. You CAN pass values but I wish it would allow returning values instead of a void in the callback. That would take us to blocks / lambda expressions and I don't think AS is ready for it...yet

Comment: Logic of your edited answer is sure way to go, only problem is facebook appearently does not accept the "id(int)/picture" syntax...and about the callback structure, i do agree, and my problem about it is that this is not properly documented on the adobe side...

Comment: So appearently i had to call fb api with absolute url, like this "https://graph.facebook.com/"+response[i].id+"/picture". So thats one problem down...but still, response from this function does not contain fields, which are described at graph explorer (url and is_sillhoulete)...

Comment: That's odd, I was able to see the response in the graph explorer with this "20001655/picture" but that's using graph explorer. So this isn't responded in the FacebookMobile.api call? Is the AS3 Facebook library parsing and stripping the responses?

Comment: Oh duh! Add "?redirect=false"! i.e. here's my json output: https://graph.facebook.com/20001655/picture?redirect=false

Comment: yep, that was exactly the problem, already solved it. Thanks anyways :)